# Connect to solr server running on localhost

Tags: python, solr, connection, server, localhost

I am attempting to connect to a [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) server using [this](https://code.google.com/p/solrpy/) tutorial. At this point, I am confident that my solr is set up correctly. I am able to run

```
> solr start -p 8983
```

and it appears to start something up.

sure enough

```
> solr status
Solr process 31421 running on port 8983
```

So now in my python code, I try what I think should be a basic connection script.

```
import solr
host = "http://localhost:8983/solr"

# also tried
# host = "http://localhost:8983"

# also tried
# host = "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr"

# also tried
# host = "http://127.0.0.1:8983"

connection = solr.SolrConnection(host)

try:
    connection.add(
        id= 1,
        title= "Lucene in Action",
        author= ['Zack', 'Hank Hill']
    )
except Exception as e:
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

connection.commit()
```

My code never makes it to the connection.commit(), instead, it hits the debug point in the exception. Looking at exception e

```
HTTP code=404, Reason=Not Found, body=<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
    <pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

So it looks like the python client is not finding the solr server, due to the 404? This seems like it should be pretty simple, so I'm not sure where I messed up here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit  : I added this script to check various hosts, no go

```
hosts = [
    'http://localhost:8983/solr',
    'http://localhost:8983',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8983'
]

def connect(host):
    connection = solr.SolrConnection(host)
    try:
        connection.add(
            id= 1,
            title='Lucene in Action',
            author= ['Zack Botkin', 'Hank Hill']
        )
    except:
        raise

for host in hosts:
    try:
        connect(host)
    except Exception as e:
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
```

Each exception is the same, 404 error

edit 2 : I was able to

```
> telnet localhost 8983
```

and it connected, so I'm pretty sure the solr server is running on that port?

Comment: What do you see if you open a browser and go to the same url "http://localhost:8983/solr" ?

Comment: if it's a remote server, can you use wget or curl to test access to the url "http://localhost:8983/solr".  Try the command: wget 'http://localhost:8983/solr'

Comment: ok, yeah, i opened "<my_ip>:8983/solr" inside a browser and can see the solr web app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To index with solr you will need to also create a core and make sure to use that core in your url.  For example, once solr has been started run this command to create a core named test:

solr create -c test

Once that has been created you should see it listed in the solr admin page.  To use it you can simply add that core name to your connection url.  Simple example python code:

```
import solr

# create a connection to a solr server
s = solr.SolrConnection('http://localhost:8983/solr/test')

# add 2 documents to the index
s.add(id=1, title='Lucene in Action', author=['bob', 'asdf'])
s.add(id=2, title='test2', author=['Joe', 'test'])
s.commit()

# do a search
response = s.query('joe')
for hit in response.results:
    print hit['title']
```

More information here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr